# OOP, attributes / functions help. Hardcoding...not sure what to do. (FIRST ATTEMPT)

Tags: python, oop, attributes

FIRST ATTEMPT at OOP.
I'm writing a game with Heroes who have several "abilities". I have a lot of repeating and don't know how to streamline this. I'm currently writing out each ability fresh and I know it's very bad...
Thanks in advance...

I feel there's a way to call something like...
"self.ability(cost, damage, defender modifier, special effect)"
Also, all "abilities" need to go through several "checks" before they are successful. This is also very clunky here but I'm not sure how to clean it up.
Thanks in advance...

```
def lightning_bolt(self):
    if self.is_stunned:
        print("Stunned...ability unsuccessful.")
    elif self.is_confused:
        confused_test = roll_d_x(2)
        if confused_test == 1:
            print("Confused...ability unsuccessful.")
    else:
        defender.mobility = (defender.mobility / 2)
        success = self.success_check()
        defender.mobility = (defender.mobility * 2)
        if success:
            volatile_roll = roll_d_x(10)
            if volatile_roll == 1:
                self.volatile_magic()
            else:
                defender.lose_health(((self.energy * 0.5) + 10))
                self.lose_energy(25)
                stun_test = roll_d_x(4)
                if stun_test == 1:
                    defender.is_stunned = True
        else:
            print("Ability failed.")

def fireball(self):
    if self.is_stunned:
        print("Stunned...ability unsuccessful.")
    elif self.is_confused:
        confused_test = roll_d_x(2)
        if confused_test == 1:
            print("Confused...ability unsuccessful.")
    else:
        defender.mobility = (defender.mobility * (3/2))
        success = self.success_check()
        defender.mobility = (defender.mobility * (2/3))
        if success:
            volatile_roll = roll_d_x(10)
            if volatile_roll == 1:
                self.volatile_magic()
            else:
                defender.lose_health((self.energy * (7/10)) + 5)
                defender.is_terrified = True
                self.lose_energy(30)
        else:
            defender.lose_health(self.energy * (1/4))
            print("Ability failed. Damage reduced.")
```

It does what I want it to, but I know there's a better way. There are 3 Heroes and 15 abilities that all need to run though the same "if self.is_stunned..." stuff. It's obviously very repetitive coding.
Thanks.

Comment: Unless you have a specific issue with the code you posted, your question possibly belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you - I'll post there when I'm allowed...restricting me to every 40-min...

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to abstract the tests to a new method:

```py
def check_status_effects(self):
    status = False
    if self.is_stunned:
        print("Stunned...ability unsuccessful.")
        status = True
    elif self.is_confused:
        confused_test = roll_d_x(2)
        if confused_test == 1:
            print("Confused...ability unsuccessful.")
        status = True
    return status
```

Then, since I assume you don't want the ability to succeed if they have a status effect, check the return of `check_status_effects` in your ability methods:

```py
def fireball(self):
    if self.check_status_effects():
        return
    # rest of ability code here
```

Comment: Okay, that's great thank you. Is there a way to create a function like "ability" that takes aspects like "cost, damage, defense modifiers"...etc so I don't have to hard-code all the integers (for damage and so on...)?